# WMF 5.0(RTM) DSC resource not being installed propery

Tags: powershell, dsc, powershell-5.0

After upgrading to WMF 5.0 DSC seems to be having problems installing my custom class based resource module.

```
PS C:\Users\alexis.coles.adm> Start-DscConfiguration -ComputerName ComputerName -Credential $autoCred -Path E:\DevResetRuntime\Mofs -Wait -Verbose -Force
VERBOSE: Perform operation 'Invoke CimMethod' with following parameters, ''methodName' = SendConfigurationApply,'className' = MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager,'namespaceName' = root/Micr
osoft/Windows/DesiredStateConfiguration'.
VERBOSE: An LCM method call arrived from computer ComputerName with user sid S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxx-3810362189-311025990-3170.
VERBOSE: [ComputerName]: LCM:  [ Start  Set      ]
VERBOSE: [ComputerName]:                            [DSCEngine] Module SxDeployment_1.11.zip downloaded.
VERBOSE: [ComputerName]:                            [DSCEngine] Resource SxDeployment version 1.11 installed.
VERBOSE: [ComputerName]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]
The PowerShell DSC resource C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SxDeployment\1.11\DscResources\PsPackageProvider does not contain the corresponding MOF file C:\Program 
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SxDeployment\1.11\DscResources\PsPackageProvider\PsPackageProvider.schema.mof. Could not install module dependencies needed by the configuration.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderSchemaFileNotFound
    + PSComputerName        : ComputerName
```

If I run this on a box that has not been upgraded it installs fine and the module is downloaded from the Resource Module Manager and extracted to the correct location.

However running this on an upgraded box only creates an empty SxDeployment folder in C:\program files\windowsPowershell\Modules.

If I copy the good extracted folder from an un-upgraded box to the new box the configuration runs fine.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

My resource zip file is named SxDeployment_1.27.zip

It just contains the following 2 files

```
SxDeployment.psd1
SxDeployment.psm1
```

I am expecting this to get extracted to the following files system structure:

```
Modules
  SxDeployment
    1.27
      SxDeployment.psd1
      SxDeployment.psm1
```

However all I get is

```
Modules
  SxDeployment
```

Comment: Can you share how does your module structure looks like?

Comment: @NanaLakshmanan Sorry for the delay in getting back to you, I have updated the question a little, please let me know anything else that might help.

Comment: can you try zipping with the 1.27 sub folder